# Richtextbox control in Provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app

Is there a way to use RichText Control in provider hosted app? I am currently using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Amit, I have removed the version tag since the question shouldn't be version specific. Free to roll back if you think it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [CKEDITOR](http://ckeditor.com/). It comes as a nuget package and you can add it in your project and use it. We have used this in provider hosted app MVC project.